# Angle between the shortest and biggest diagonals of a Decagon.

Tags: geometry, polygons

I've been doing some geometry lately and approached this problem. I need to get an angle between the biggest and shortest diagonals of a Decagon (10 sided polygon). As the book says I will get only 1 point in this task so this is "easy". Is there some formula to calculate the angle between diagonals of an N sided polygon? Or what is the formula in Decagon? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider a triangle from two sides of decagon and the shortest diagonal, then find its angles. The angle with you are looking for is half of bigger angle minus smaller angle (draw a picture). Internal angle in this polygon is $\frac{8*180^\circ}{10}$

Comment: Is there any way without drawing? I mean some formula for N sided polygons?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, but you have internal angle $\frac{(n-2)*180^{\circ}}{n}$, not $144^{\circ}$.